# vb.net - how do I parse a percentage value from a grid cell?

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I'm trying to parse a formatted percentage value back from a datagridviewcell that has been set with the "P" formatter:

`double percent = 0.96`
`cell.value = percent.tostring("p")`

gives me a displayed value of 96 % which is what I want.

Now what I'm looking for is something like what is provided for the other formatting strings - NumberStyles.HexNumber, Currency etc
so that I can do this

`double percent= double.parse( cell.value, NumberStyles.Percent )`

which would give me a percent value of .96

I have scoured the .net documentation but can't find any sort of AllowPercent style like the others - is there one?

p.s. I see there is another question here like this and tried to expand on it in that thread, but was deleted by a moderator and told to post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to do something like this

```
double dVal = double.Parse(cell.value.Replace("%","")) / 100;
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. It forces me to treat the 'P' formatted fields differently than all the other formatted fields.